# How to calculate the number of months and days between two dates, without returning negative values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff

I have this SQL block working in most situations but am returning a negative "day" value when the the month/day of the end date is > than the month/day of the start date. Not quite sure how to prevent negative day results from happening other than wrapping this in a case when to catch the exceptions when end month/day is > start month/day.

For example, if the start date is 2017 - 06 -05 and the end date is 2019 - 06 - 04, the output is "24 months and -1 days".

```
CONVERT ( VARCHAR ( MAX ),
DATEDIFF ( month , [Participant - Birthday] , [Event - Event Date] ) ) 

+ ' months and ' + 

CONVERT ( VARCHAR ( MAX ) , 
DATEDIFF ( day , DATEADD ( month , DATEDIFF ( month , [Participant - Birthday] , [Event - Event Date] ) , [Participant - Birthday] ) , [Event - Event Date] ) ) 

+ ' days'
```

Expected out put using the above start and end date should be "23 months and 30 days".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way of expressing the logic:

```
select s, e, v.num_months, datediff(day, dateadd(month, num_months, s), e)
from (values (convert(date, '2017-06-05'), convert(date, '2019-06-04')),
             (convert(date, '2017-06-05'), convert(date, '2019-06-05')),
             (convert(date, '2017-06-05'), convert(date, '2019-06-06'))
     ) t(s, e) cross apply
     (values (case when day(s) <= day(e) then datediff(month, s, e) else datediff(month, s, e) - 1 end)) v(num_months);
```

This calculates the number of months difference -- up to or before the end date.  It then calculates the day difference between the end date and the start date plus that number of months.